# Spring security cannot access userService while login NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

When making post request to login this error shows up telling me that userService is null.
When I create an object of UserService instead of autowiring it it passes it but tell me that the repository called in userService is null. The repository is autowired and i cannot instanciate it because its an interface.

Here is the service class:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return new MyUserDetails(userService.getByUsernameOrEmail(s));
    }
}
```

And this is the security configuration class:
Also I am creating an object of MyUserService because spring cannot autowire it telling me that no bean have such name.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class UserSercurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(new MyUserDetailsService());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole(UserType.ADMIN.toString())
                .and().formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate method or variables in your repository as it is an interface but you can autowire your repository class to use your method declared in userRepository interface, you have to autowire your repository class.You can do it this way as I have done in the below code.
Your service class should be like this:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Users user = userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
    }
    return new MyUserDetails(user);
 }
```

And your repository should be like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.name = ?1")
  public Users getUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

And also autowire UserDetailsService in your configuration class and pass the instance userDetailsService in your configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) method, UserDetailsService provides you instance of your MyUserDetailService class.

```
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired
 UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

Try to implement in this way, If this is solution of your question please let me know and if you still have doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: Intellij underlines userDetailsService telling me Could not autowhire, no bean of UserDetailsService found but the app compiles and it works, thank you